# Imprimir funciones multi hilo

Tags: c++, hilos

Tengo este código, y como verán, dentro de las funciones pongo el `cout` para imprimir el llenado de los arreglos, pero la profesora dijo que eso no es permitido.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

void primerHilo()
{
    int i = 100;
    int arreglo[i];
    for (arreglo[i] = 0; arreglo[i] < 100; arreglo[i]++)
    {
        arreglo[i] = arreglo[i] * 1;
        ///cout << arreglo[i] << "\n"; NOT ALLOWED
    }
}

void segundoHilo()
{
    int i = 100;
    int arreglo2[i];
    for (arreglo2[i] = 0; arreglo2[i] < 100; arreglo2[i]++)
    {
        arreglo2[i] = arreglo2[i] * 2;
        ///cout << arreglo2[i] << "\n"; NOT ALLOWED
    }
}

int main()
{
    cout << "\nTAREA 14//MULTI-HILOS Y ORDENAMIENTO\n";
    cout << "Llenado concurrente de 5 arreglos" << endl << "\n";

    thread llenadoUno(primerHilo);
    llenadoUno.join();

    thread llenadoDos(segundoHilo);
    llenadoDos.join();
}
```

El punto es llenar los arreglos en manera concurrente. Después, imprimirlos **fuera de la concurrencia**, o sea fuera de su función. Pero no tengo idea de cómo hacerlo.

Después tengo que ordenarlos. ¿Algunos tips?

Comment: ¿Te has dado cuenta que escribes siempre en la posición `100` de los arreglos? Dicha posición está fuera del ámbito del arreglo. Además no puedes declarar un arreglo con un tamaño obtenido de una variable.

Answer (score 3):

Lo que te comenta tu profesora no es que esté prohibido... es simplemente que *puede* producir efectos indeseados. Si dos o más hilos hacen uso de un recurso compartido puede suceder que los accesos a dicho recurso se solapen, haciendo que la información almacenada en dicho recurso no sea legible. En tu caso el recurso compartido es la salida estándar. Si un hilo intenta escribir "1111" y el segundo hilo "2222", puede suceder que la salida sea "1111222" o también "12212211" o cualquier combinación lineal que se te ocurra... como es de imaginar no es un efecto deseado.

Por otro lado, tus bucles no tienen ningún sentido:

```
void primerHilo()
{
    int i = 100;
    int arreglo[i]; // 1
    for (arreglo[i] = 0; arreglo[i] < 100; arreglo[i]++) // 2
    {
        arreglo[i] = arreglo[i] * 1;
        ///cout << arreglo[i] << "\n"; NOT ALLOWED
    }
}
```

Los problemas son los siguientes:

1. El arreglo, tal y como lo has declarado, es un VLA (Variable-Length Array) y no es una característica contemplada en el estándar de C++ (aunque sí lo está en el estándar de C). Esto quiere decir que pese a que algunos compiladores lo admitan no deberías confiarte porque en otros no funcionará.
2. ¿Por qué declaras un arreglo de 100 posiciones si únicamente usas una? Y no solo es que únicamente uses una... es que la posición que estás usando **no pertenece al arreglo**. Si el arreglo tiene 100 posiciones, los índices válidos se encuentran en el rango (0,99), luego acceder a `arreglo[100]` no es una opción salvo que quieras pisar memoria de otras variables.

Un último problema lo vas a encontrar en la gestión de los propios hilos:

```
thread llenadoUno(primerHilo);
llenadoUno.join();

thread llenadoDos(segundoHilo);
llenadoDos.join();
```

Las llamadas a `join` son bloqueantes hasta que el hilo finaliza. El efecto es que la llamada a `llenadoUno.join()` bloqueará el hilo principal hasta que dicho hilo finalice... y después se ejecutará el segundo hilo, por lo que la concurrencia en este caso brillará por su ausencia. Las llamadas a `join` deberían ir juntas y siempre después de haber creado todos los hilos:

```
thread llenadoUno(primerHilo);

thread llenadoDos(segundoHilo);

llenadoUno.join();
llenadoDos.join();
```

Bueno, una vez solucionado este punto vamos (para hacer nuestras pruebas) a modificar un poco las funciones que se ejecutan sobre los hilos:

```
void primerHilo()
{
    int arreglo;
    for (arreglo = 0; arreglo < 5; arreglo++)
    {
        arreglo = arreglo * 1;
        cout << "primerHilo: " << arreglo << "\n";
    }
}
```

Y ahora el main:

```
int main()
{
    thread llenadoUno(primerHilo);
    thread llenadoDos(segundoHilo);

    llenadoUno.join();
    llenadoDos.join();
}
```

Si ejecutamos este programa una posible salida será:

```
primerHilo: segundoHilo: 0
segundoHilo: 1
segundoHilo: 2
segundoHilo: 3
segundoHilo: 4
0
primerHilo: 1
primerHilo: 2
primerHilo: 3
primerHilo: 4
```

Como ves, las salidas se solapan y el resultado no es para nada elegante.

El ejercicio lo puedes completar de diferentes formas. Personalmente creo que la más sencilla es hacer uso de `std::mutex`. Los mutex permiten controlar el acceso a zonas críticas y, pese a que son algo más pesados que los semáforos, su uso es extremadamente simple, lo que ayuda mucho a prevenir condiciones de carrera y abrazos mortales. Nota que el mutex a utilizar debe ser el mismo en ambos hilos para que el bloqueo sea correcto.

En este caso quizás la opción más sencilla puede ser declarar el mutex como variable global. Que conste que declarar variables globales no suele ser la mejor opción, pero considero que en este caso lo que te interesa aprender es el manejo de hilos y no la declaración de variables.

Lo que hay que hacer entonces es bloquear el mutex durante la llamada a `cout`:

```
std::mutex miMutex;

void primerHilo()
{
    int arreglo;
    for (arreglo = 0; arreglo < 5; arreglo++)
    {
        arreglo = arreglo * 1;

        miMutex.lock();
        cout << "primerHilo: " << arreglo << "\n";
        miMutex.unlock();
    }
}
```

Si ejecutas el programa así un posible resultado será:

```
primerHilo: 0
primerHilo: 1
primerHilo: 2
primerHilo: 3
primerHilo: 4
segundoHilo: 0
segundoHilo: 1
segundoHilo: 2
segundoHilo: 3
segundoHilo: 4
```

Como ves la salidas ya no se pisan pero... ¿y la concurrencia? El programa aunque no lo parezca sí que se está ejecutando de forma concurrente, lo que sucede es que el hilo que se queda bloqueado no está comprobando el bloqueo de forma constante sino que, en caso de encontrar el bloqueo, se duerme un ligero período de tiempo... tiempo que el otro hilo aprovecha para volver a bloquear el mutex.

Si añadimos un retardo lo suficientemente grande dentro de la función la cosa cambia. Este retardo podemos simularlo con `sleep` o mediante un bucle:

```
for (arreglo = 0; arreglo < 5; arreglo++)
{
  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> iolock(miMutex);
    cout << "primerHilo: " << arreglo << "std::en;
  }
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
}
```

Otro cambio es que he pasado a usar `std::lock_guard` para que gestione el bloqueo del mutex por mí. Lo que hace `std::lock_guard` es llamar a `mutex.lock()` al crearse y llamar a `mutex.unlock()` al destruirse. Si no entiendes o no te convence su uso puedes dejar el uso manual del primer ejemplo. Eso sí, procura dejar la llamada a `sleep_for` fuera del bloqueo.

Con estos cambios la salida del programa lucirá así (por ejemplo):

```
primerHilo: 0
segundoHilo: 0
primerHilo: 1
segundoHilo: 1
segundoHilo: 2
primerHilo: 2
primerHilo: 3
segundoHilo: 3
segundoHilo: 4
primerHilo: 4
```

Si lo que deseas es mover `cout` fuera de la función tendrás que hacer más trabajo:

- Cada función tendrá que almacenar su estado en una variable que no sea local.
- Para no mostrar valores repetidos, al modificar la variable comentada en el punto anterior debería ademas activar un flag para indicar que se ha producido un cambio
- El hilo principal deberá disponer de un bucle en el que compruebe los flags del punto anterior y, en caso de estar activos, mostrar el estado de la variable asociada.

Como ahora tenemos que gestionar un bucle en el main necesitamos tener constancia de cuándo terminan los hilos para abandonar dicho bucle. Esta tarea se puede hacer, entre otras opciones, con `std::future` o con `std::atomic`. El ejemplo lo voy a realizar con `std::atomic` que no es más que una variable a la que no puede acceder más que un hilo a la vez. La idea es inicializarla con el número de hilos que están corriendo, entonces cuando un hilo termina su trabajo decrementa dicha variable y cuando la variable valga 0 podemos abandonar el bucle.

El main ahora podría quedar tal que así:

```
struct Mensajero
{
  int valor; // Almacena el valor actual
  bool flag; // Para indicar que el valor ha cambiado

  Mensajero()
   : flag(false)
  {}
};

int main()
{
  Mensajero mensajeros[2];
  std::atomic<int> running(2); // Use an atomic flag.

  thread t1(primerHilo,std::ref(mensajeros[0]),std::ref(running));
  thread t2(segundoHilo,std::ref(mensajeros[1]),std::ref(running));

  // bucle hasta que los hilos terminen
  while (running != 0)
  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> iolock(miMutex);

    for( int i=0; i<2; i++ )
    {
      if( mensajeros[i].flag )
      {
        mensajeros[i].flag = false;
        std::cout << "Hilo " << i << ": " << mensajeros[i].valor << '\n';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`std::ref` sirve para poder pasar referencias a las funciones. No es más que un envoltorio. Piensa que los parámetros de `std::thread` están establecidos por valor, luego nos tenemos que valer de algún truco para sortear dicha interfaz.

Los hilos lucirían entonces así:

```
void primerHilo(Mensajero& mensajero,std::atomic<int>& running)
{
    int arreglo;
    for (arreglo = 0; arreglo < 5; arreglo++)
    {
      {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> iolock(miMutex);
        mensajero.flag = true; // Indicamos que el valor ha cambiado
        mensajero.valor = arreglo; // Nuevo valor
      }
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }

  // Finaliza el hilo, decrementamos el número de hilos en ejecución
  running--;
}
```

Y una posible salida del programa será entonces:

```
Hilo 0: 0
Hilo 1: 0
Hilo 0: 1
Hilo 1: 1
Hilo 0: 2
Hilo 1: 2
Hilo 0: 3
Hilo 1: 3
Hilo 1: 4
Hilo 0: 4
```

Como te he comentado, verificar que el hilo ha terminado es algo que también se puede hacer con `std::future`, pero la teoría que va detrás es sustancialmente mayor y ya se ha alargado bastante el hilo. Si necesitas más información solo tienes que preguntar.

Answer (score 2):

Es **imposible** que accedas a tus `arreglo` desde fuera de tus funciones, puesto que los has declarado **locales** a la función, y son eliminados cuando sales de esta. Deberías repasar el concepto de **ámbito** de las variables.

Ademas, `join` bloquea hasta que **un** hilo termina, osea que, en realidad, estás llamando a tus funciones `primerHilo` y `segundoHilo` de forma secuencial. Los `threads` están precisamente para hacer cosas de forma **concurrente**, a la vez.

Si lo que quieres es rellenar **un** unico array desde 2 hilos, sería:

1. Crear una función que rellene un array, desde la posición inicial, pero *saltandonos* un elemento, es decir, un `for( idx = inicio; idx < fin; idx += 2 ) { ... }`
2. Crear un array dentro de la función main, **de un número par de elementos**.
3. Crear 2 hilos, llamando a tu función de llenado, pero que en la primera llamada empiece por el índice 0, y la segunda por el indice 1.
4. Esperar a que **ambos** hilos acaben.
5. Mostrar el resultado.

Si lo que quieres es rellenar **dos** arrays, seria similar:

1. Crear una función que rellene un array `for( idx = inicio; idx < fin; ++idx ) { ... }`
2. Crear **2** array dentro de la función main, `array1[]` y `array2[]`.
3. Crear 2 hilos, llamando a tu función de llenado, pero que en la primera llamada rellene el `array1[]`, y la segunda rellene el `array2[]`.
4. Esperar a que **ambos** hilos acaben.
5. Mostrar el resultado.